# How to combine two corpus

Tags: python, nlp

I have **corpus** and **corpus_1**, and both sizes are 1*3000, the first corpus is described as the **'Headline'** and second corpus(corpus_1) describe as the **'text'** of the Headline. 
how I can make only final corpus in **pandas.** 
Eg: **"corpus_final = corpus + corpus_1"**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `apply` and `join`:

```
df["final"] = df.apply(lambda x: "".join(
    [
        str(x.corpus),
        str(x.corpus_1)
    ]
), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **corpus** variable you describe is called **string**. Summing a **string**, in development, is called **concatenation**. To concatenate two strings in python, you simply do:

```
finalstring = string1 + string2
```

In pandas, you can use:

```
data = data["your column"].str.cat(new column, sep =" ")
```